# Render html views for multiple clients

Tags: javascript, html, http, token, jwt

I'm writing a `Node.js` server that answers to HTTP GET requests with a dynamic HTML page, rendered "on-the-fly" with some data retrieved according to the client requests.

To identify each client I use a session token (JWT) and this is sent back to the server as query parameter in each GET request, along with the other information, i.e.:

```
my.domain/api/service?token=blablabla&req=123
```

It works, indeed. I wonder if sending the session tokens as query parameters is a good (and safe) idea.
I would send it in the headers, but it's harder on the client's page because now I just set an `href` tag to the url above.

Do you recommend another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security wise, doesn't really matter how you send it, as long as it doesn't contain sensitive information (*e.g* password) because it's not encrypted, it's encoded and token can be decoded very easily.

Even if someone (hacker, user *etc*) alters the token, server will verify and notice that (if you've set up verification correctly) and you can deny access to page, media, data or whatever your user requests.

**Important!** **Use SSL!** Otherwise hacker can steal the token from its owner and use it himself, server only checks if it's valid and not altered, not where it came from. Read more: [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

---

How you do it, is totally up to you and your project, however I would personally send it *via* header.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I really need to read something about how to use SSL. I will try to send the token via header.